# Kendo UI display UTC to AEST / AEDT

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid that fetches data from API by AJAX call.
It has a column with date and the date is coming from backend in this format `"2022-03-08T19:02:00"`.

This is one of the column of my grid where I am parsing the date :

```
{
                        field: "createdDate",
                        title: "Created Date",
                        template:"<div class='createdDateTemplate'>#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(createdDate)) #</div>",
                        width: 150
                    }
```

I want to display this date in AEST or AEDT which ever is being followed . Is this possible from the template itself ?

EDIT :

I know that Kendo automatically renders date time in local format something like this for me:

GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)

But is it possible to display this time with +10 added to time itself ?

Edit: I am trying this
`template:"<div class='createdDateTemplate'>#= kendo.toString(kendo.timezone.convert(kendo.parseDate(createdDate), 'Etc/UTC', 'Etc/GMT+10'), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt') #</div>",`
but I am getting this error:
`Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getFullYear')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kendo automatically converts the dates to the user's local time if you add zzz to the end of date , like this `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz`.
One more thing , you say that your date is UTC but it doesn't have a Z (zero utc offset) at the end. Kendo won't add the offset without it , so I would recommend adding it.
Maybe you could try something like this:

```
#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(modifiedDate+'Z','yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz'), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt')#
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can display the date however you like it. Read the Kendo Date Parsing documentation. I would suggest though that the back-end send it in ISO format (e.g. `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`). So that on the front-end, you can just do `parseDate` without the need for additional parameters. Perhaps depending on the language setting of the browser it will be shown in AEST or AEDT format. If not, then you can do `toString` on the date.

Comment: I have seen the documentation but couldn't find how to convert datetime to one of the two timezones , since they use either AEST or AEDT. I was hoping if this conversion would be done automatically based on what Timezone they are following.

Comment: Like I said "Perhaps depending on the language setting of the browser it will be shown in AEST or AEDT format." As for converting to AEST/AEDT, have you tried googling the format? It should be something like `toString(date, 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss')`.